# How can I compare magnetism/mass ratio of different magnets?

Tags: mass, magnetic-fields

I want to compare the magnetism/mass ratio of different magnets. Let, for example be ceramic/samarium-cobalt/alnico/steel/neodymium magnets.

Questions:

1. What units should I compare for magnetism/mass ratio?
2. I am confused trying to understand what are the differences among Tesla / Henry / Oersted / Gauss / Weber units. Can somebody explain?
3. Where can I get tables comparing magnetism/mass ratio of different materials' magnets?

Comment: I'm not sure how/why $B/m$ would be a useful measure for anything, but you can use whatever units you want. Probably easiest in common units (i.e., SI or cgs).

Comment: What is the purpose of this experiment? @sergiol

Comment: Know what type of magnets have stronger magnetic attraction/repulsion power relatively to their mass — @Andy